# Counting appointments for each day using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by

I'm in trouble with a mysql statement counting appointments for one day within a given time period. I've got a calendar table including starting and finishing column (type = DateTime). The following statement should count all appointments for November including overall appointments:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT('APPOINTMENTS') AS Count, 
    DATE(c.StartingDate) AS Datum 
FROM t_calendar c
    WHERE 
        c.GUID = 'blalblabla' AND
        ((DATE(c.StartingDate) <= DATE('2012-11-01 00:00:00')) AND (DATE(c.EndingDate) >= DATE('2012-11-30 23:59:59'))) OR
        ((DATE(c.StartingDate) >= DATE('2012-11-01 00:00:00')) AND (DATE(c.EndingDate) <= DATE('2012-11-30 23:59:59')))
    GROUP BY DATE(c.StartingDate)
    HAVING Count > 1
```

**But how to include appointments that starts before a StartingDate and ends on the StartingDate?**

e.g.

- StartingDate = 2012-11-14 17:00:00, EndingDate = 2012-11-15 08:00:00
- StartingDate = 2012-11-15 09:00:00, EndingDate = 2012-11-15 10:00:00
- StartingDate = 2012-11-15 11:00:00, EndingDate = 2012-11-15 12:00:00

My statement returns a count of 2 for 15th of November. But that's wrong because the first appointment is missing. How to include these appointments? What I am missing, UNION SELECT, JOIN, sub selection?

---

### A possible solution?

```
SELECT 
    c1.GUID, COUNT('APPOINTMENTS') + COUNT(DISTINCT c2.ANYFIELD) AS Count, 
    DATE(c1.StartingDate) AS Datum,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c2.ANYFIELD)
FROM 
    t_calendar c1
LEFT JOIN
    t_calendar c2
        ON
            c2.ResourceGUID = c1.ResourceGUID AND
            (DATE(c2.EndingDate) = DATE(c1.StartingDate)) AND 
            (DATE(c2.StartingDate) < DATE(c1.StartingDate))
WHERE 
    ((DATE(c1.StartingDate) <= DATE('2012-11-01 00:00:00')) AND (DATE(c1.EndingDate) >= DATE('2012-11-30 23:59:59'))) OR
    ((DATE(c1.StartingDate) >= DATE('2012-11-01 00:00:00')) AND (DATE(c1.EndingDate) <= DATE('2012-11-30 23:59:59')))    
GROUP BY 
    c1.ResourceGUID,
    DATE(c1.StartingDate)
```

Comment: What should your *possible solution* do anyway? It seems you're overcomplicating things and joining on data we don't even know about... Have you tried my final solution with numbers table that is much simpler and returns exactly what you require?

Comment: Your `join` search condition doesn't seem to make sense unless you have appointments that can have starting dates **after** ending dates... Writing queries is easier if you do it step by step so each change you add is simple enough to handle and understand. **Or you really didn't make yourself clear what you'd like to accomplish**. Click on my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70146/30) and you'll see correct results that are correct and perform well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### First: Consolidate range checking

First of all your two range `where` conditions can be replaced by a single one. And it also seems that you're only counting appointments that either completely overlap target date range or are completely contained within. Partially overlapping ones aren't included. Hence your question about appointments that end right on the range starting date.

To make `where` clause easily understandable I'll simplify it by using:

- two variables to define target range:

  - `rangeStart` (in your case 1st Nov 2012)
  - `rangeEnd` (I'll rather assume to 1st Dec 2012 00:00:00.00000)
- won't be converting `datetime` to dates only (using `date` function) the way that you did, but you can easily do that.

With these in mind your `where` clause can be greatly simplified and covers all appointments for given range:

```
...
where (c.StartingDate < rangeEnd) and (c.EndingDate >= rangeStart)
...
```

This will search for all appointments that fall in target range and will cover all these appointment cases:

```
                           start          end
target range               |==============|

partial front       |---------|
partial back                            |---------|
total overlap          |---------------------|
total containment               |-----|
```

Partial front/back may also barely *touch* your target range (what you've been after).

### Second: Resolving the problem

Why you're missing the first record? Simply because of your `having` clause that only collects those groups that have **more than 1 appointment starting on a given day**: 15th Nov has two, but 14th has only one and is therefore excluded because `Count = 1` and is not `> 1`.

To answer your second question *what am I missing* is: you're not missing anything, actually you have too much in your statement and needs to simplified.

Try this statement instead that should return exactly what you're after:

```
select count(c.GUID) as Count,
       date(c.StartingDate) as Datum
from t_calendar c
where (c.GUID = 'blabla') and
      (c.StartingDate < str_to_date('2012-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d') and
      (c.EndingDate >= str_to_date('2012-11-01', '%Y-%m-%d'))
group by date(c.StartingDate)
```

I used `str_to_date` function to make string to date conversion more safe.

I'm not really sure why you included `having` in your statement, because it's not really needed. Unless your actual statement is more complex and you only included part that's most relevant. In that case you'll likely have to change it to:

```
having Count > 0
```

### Getting appointment count per day in any given date range

There are likely other ways as well but the most common way would be using a *numbers* or ?calendar* table that gives you the ability to break a range into individual *points* - days. They you have to join your appointments to this numbers table and provide results.

I've [created a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70146/30) that does the trick. Here's what it does...

Suppose you have numbers table `Num` with numbers from 0 to *x*. And appointments table `Cal` with your records. Following script created these two tables and populates some data. Numbers are only up to 100 which is enough for 3 months worth of data.

```
-- appointments
create table Cal (
  Id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  StartDate datetime not null,
  EndDate datetime not null
);

-- create appointments
insert Cal (StartDate, EndDate)
values
  ('2012-10-15 08:00:00', '2012-10-20 16:00:00'),
  ('2012-10-25 08:00:00', '2012-11-01 03:00:00'),
  ('2012-11-01 12:00:00', '2012-11-01 15:00:00'),
  ('2012-11-15 10:00:00', '2012-11-16 10:00:00'),
  ('2012-11-20 08:00:00', '2012-11-30 08:00:00'),
  ('2012-11-30 22:00:00', '2012-12-05 00:00:00'),
  ('2012-12-01 05:00:00', '2012-12-10 12:00:00');

-- numbers table
create table Nums (
  Id int not null primary key
);

-- add 100 numbers
insert into Nums
select a.a + (10 * b.a)
from (select 0 as a union all
      select 1 union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3 union all
      select 4 union all
      select 5 union all
      select 6 union all
      select 7 union all
      select 8 union all
      select 9) as a,
     (select 0 as a union all
      select 1 union all
      select 2 union all
      select 3 union all
      select 4 union all
      select 5 union all
      select 6 union all
      select 7 union all
      select 8 union all
      select 9) as b
```

Now what you have to do now is

1. **Select a range of days** which you do by selecting numbers from `Num` table and convert them to dates.
2. Then **join your appointments** to those dates so that those appointments that fall on particular day are joined to that particular day
3. Then just **group all these appointments per each day** and get results

Here's the code that does this:

```
-- just in case so comparisons don't trip over
set names 'latin1' collate latin1_general_ci;

-- start and end target date range
set @s := str_to_date('2012-11-01', '%Y-%m-%d');
set @e := str_to_date('2012-12-01', '%Y-%m-%d');

-- get appointment count per day within target range of days
select adddate(@s, n.Id) as Day, count(c.Id) as Appointments
from Nums n
  left join Cal c
  on ((date(c.StartDate) <= adddate(@s, n.Id)) and (date(c.EndDate) >= adddate(@s, n.Id)))
where adddate(@s, n.Id) < @e
group by Day;
```

And this is the result of this rather simple select statement:

```
|        DAY | APPOINTMENTS |
-----------------------------
| 2012-11-01 |            2 |
| 2012-11-02 |            0 |
| 2012-11-03 |            0 |
| 2012-11-04 |            0 |
| 2012-11-05 |            0 |
| 2012-11-06 |            0 |
| 2012-11-07 |            0 |
| 2012-11-08 |            0 |
| 2012-11-09 |            0 |
| 2012-11-10 |            0 |
| 2012-11-11 |            0 |
| 2012-11-12 |            0 |
| 2012-11-13 |            0 |
| 2012-11-14 |            0 |
| 2012-11-15 |            1 |
| 2012-11-16 |            1 |
| 2012-11-17 |            0 |
| 2012-11-18 |            0 |
| 2012-11-19 |            0 |
| 2012-11-20 |            1 |
| 2012-11-21 |            1 |
| 2012-11-22 |            1 |
| 2012-11-23 |            1 |
| 2012-11-24 |            1 |
| 2012-11-25 |            1 |
| 2012-11-26 |            1 |
| 2012-11-27 |            1 |
| 2012-11-28 |            1 |
| 2012-11-29 |            1 |
| 2012-11-30 |            2 |
```

Comment: Hey! Thank's a lot. I've just changed the range checking! But my problem is not solved. I want to add the number of appointments ending on the 15th of november to the 15th of november only if their starting date is before the 15th of november...

e.g. 
- 2012.11.14 COUNT = 1
- 2012.11.15 COUNT = **3**!

Comment: @user1696336: Ok. What you actually want is to get counts of all appointments that fall on a particular day regardless of their start and end times? Is that correct?

Comment: I know... I just tried sub selection and join but I haven't solved the problem. I hope you find any solution :)

Comment: @user1696336: Ok that's not an easy task because it seems you'll have to extrapolate records...

Comment: hmm... but i don't know how to do this within a statement

Comment: @user1696336: Here you go. I've written it all for you. Given a date range start and end date you can get count of appointments per each day that fall on specific day...

Comment: Sorry, i've been down for a while :( 
Pretty cool :) Just the best solution ever seen!!! Thx :)!